# How to fix Textarea field Help Text(?) position in Oracle Apex 18.2?

Tags: oracle-apex

We have recently upgraded oracle apex from 5.0.3 to 18.2 version. After upgrade Help text(?) position changed and showing just below the Textarea field.

I am having a challenge to see the Help text(?) position right next to the Textarea field.

Comment: What happens if you maximize the browser window?

Comment: Hi, even I maximize the window, still the Help text symbol(?) showing below the textarea field.

Comment: Hm. I was hoping it'll *move* to a desired position.

Comment: unfortunately it did not move.  :(

Comment: Right; maybe it is a bug which has been fixed in 19.1. I've just checked (as I have access to both 18.2 (on my server) and 19.1 (on apex.oracle.com) - on 19.1, (?) is placed on the right side of the text area.